# Xcode 12 update 'AFNetworking' Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, build, updates, xcode12

After I've updated my project for Xcode 12 i got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWMC6.jpg)

I'm not sure what is it. Also this is my podsfile:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMhan.png)

Answer (score 0):

In you Pod file remove the version "1.3.0".

Only write,

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
```

Save the file and install the pods again for your project.